# How to include local dependencies in my ant build

Tags: java, ant

At present I have the following build.xml:

```
<project name="Bccn" default="help" basedir=".">
<!-- Define the properties used by the build -->
<property name="app.name" value="bccn" />
<property name="app.version" value="0.1-dev" />
<property name="tcserver.home" value="/home/abhishek/tomcat" />
<property name="work.home" value="${basedir}/work" />
<property name="dist.home" value="${basedir}/dist" />
<property name="src.home" value="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="web.home" value="${basedir}/web" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />

<target name="help">
    <echo>You can use the following targets:</echo>
    <echo>
    </echo>
    <echo>  help    : (default) Prints this message </echo>
    <echo>  all     : Cleans, compiles, and packages application</echo>
    <echo>  clean   : Deletes work directories</echo>
    <echo>  compile : Compiles servlets into class files</echo>
    <echo>  dist    : Packages artifacts into a deployable WAR</echo>
    <echo>
    </echo>
    <echo>For example, to clean, compile, and package all at once, run:</echo>
    <echo>prompt> ant all </echo>
</target>

<!-- Define the CLASSPATH -->
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${tcserver.home}/bin">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${tcserver.home}/lib" />
    <fileset dir="${tcserver.home}/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="all" depends="clean,compile,dist" description="Clean work dirs, then compile and create a WAR" />

<target name="clean" description="Delete old work and dist directories">
    <delete dir="${work.home}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.home}" />
</target>

<target name="prepare" depends="clean" description="Create working dirs and copy static files to work dir">
    <mkdir dir="${dist.home}" />
    <mkdir dir="${work.home}/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <!-- Copy static HTML and JSP files to work dir -->
    <copy todir="${work.home}">
        <fileset dir="${web.home}" />
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="Compile Java sources and copy to WEB-INF/classes dir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.home}" destdir="${work.home}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>

    <copy todir="${work.home}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${src.home}" excludes="**/*.java" />
    </copy>

</target>


<target name="dist" depends="compile" description="Create WAR file for binary distribution">
    <jar jarfile="${dist.home}/${app.name}-${app.version}.war" basedir="${work.home}" />

</target>
```

Now I included log4j as a local dependency and want to include it when I create my .war file. However, ANT is not able to find the dependency. Is there a way to get it working? Sorry for the basic question, I am a noob at it.

**Update (and thanks for the help I got already):**

I didn't want to add the "war" thing so I modified my build.xml as follows:
        
    ``

```
<target name="help">
    <echo>You can use the following targets:</echo>
    <echo>
    </echo>
    <echo>  help    : (default) Prints this message </echo>
    <echo>  all     : Cleans, compiles, and packages application</echo>
    <echo>  clean   : Deletes work directories</echo>
    <echo>  compile : Compiles servlets into class files</echo>
    <echo>  dist    : Packages artifacts into a deployable WAR</echo>
    <echo>
    </echo>
    <echo>For example, to clean, compile, and package all at once, run:</echo>
    <echo>prompt> ant all </echo>
</target>

<!-- Define the CLASSPATH -->
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${tcserver.home}/bin">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${tcserver.home}/lib" />
    <fileset dir="${tcserver.home}/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="all" depends="clean,compile,dist" description="Clean work dirs, then compile and create a WAR" />

<target name="clean" description="Delete old work and dist directories">
    <delete dir="${work.home}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.home}" />
</target>

<target name="prepare" depends="clean" description="Create working dirs and copy static files to work dir">
    <mkdir dir="${dist.home}" />
    <mkdir dir="${work.home}/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <!-- Copy static HTML and JSP files to work dir -->
    <copy todir="${work.home}">
        <fileset dir="${web.home}" />
    </copy>

</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="Compile Java sources and copy to WEB-INF/classes dir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.home}" destdir="${work.home}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>

    <copy todir="${work.home}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${src.home}" excludes="**/*.java" />
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </copy>

</target>


<target name="dist" depends="compile" description="Create WAR file for binary distribution">
    <jar jarfile="${dist.home}/${app.name}-${app.version}.war" basedir="${work.home}" />

</target>
```

Now ANT can find the dependencies and compile it. However when I deploy it to a Tomcat server, it fails to file the dependencies. Can you please provide some ideas as to how I can package the dependencies so its visible to Tomcat as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [war task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) instead:

```
<war destfile="${warname}" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <fileset dir="${work.home}"/>
    <lib dir="${lib.dir}/" includes="log4j.jar"/>
    <classes dir = "${CLASSES}" />
</war>
```

You can configure it to find the dependency jars to be included in your war file and to specify the path to the web.xml folder. You shouldn't be coping the .class files to the destination in the war folder, let the war task do it for you.

Comment: Fails at the compilation stage stating that the library was not found.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that you already had a library folder defined, make sure that the ${lib.dir} folder contains the log4j.jar

Comment: @Abhishek The webxml path should point to the real path, I am just asuming it is in war/WEB-INF/web.xml, and you should define the warname property.